# Any way to reduce the camera lag in python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

On running the script, the camera works and I am able to get the video, but the video output is very slow.
There's very much time difference in between the frames causing a laggy video output on the screen.

Is there any way to reduce the lag and increase the Frame Rate?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import cv2
import time

t = time.time()
frames = 0
while True:
    frames += 1
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    check, frame = video.read()

    print(frame)

    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1, 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("LIVE", gray)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
print("Frame Rate = ", end="")
print((time.time()-t) / frames)
```

I expected a frame rate of around 24-25, but I am getting frame rate of around 1.76 .

Comment: What camera? What computer? What OS? Which OpenCV version? How are you displaying the image?

Comment: `video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` should be outside of the while loop, just right before the while loop.

Comment: @HaBom thanks that helped... The video is smooth now..

But now, the output in console is coming "Frame Rate = 0.050371124033342325
".. which is inaccurate ..

Comment: @idaljeetsingh because the `t = time.time()` should be inside the while loop, just right at the beginning of the while loop.

Comment: @HaBom if it will be inside the loop it will give even less output as on last iteration, the  time will be very-very close to the time of frame rate calculation at [ print((time.time()-t) / frames)]

Comment: @idaljeetsingh oh I see, it should be `print(1/((time.time()-t) / frames))`. Above you just calculate the time to process a frame.

Comment: Thanks that worked!!